# How to check if strings are similar

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy

I have the following strings

```
text
USA guidances/regulations
US guidances/regulations
96
text
US guidances/regulations
US guidances/regulations
100
text
Australia guidances/regulations
US guidances/regulations
92
text
China Guidances/Regulations
US guidances/regulations
92
text
EU guidances/regulations
US guidances/regulations
98
```

First one under text is input string and the second is the one against which it is matched. Last is their fuzzywuzzy ratio. I'm matching it like this:

```
ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(t.lower(), txt.lower())
```

If the country name is different it should return a lower score as opposed to when it is similar. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does it always start with the country name? If yes, you can compare the first words of both lines separately.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the question. What happens when you try your existing code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen. Be specific, and show test cases that clearly point to the exact differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you've provided, the text to compare seems to have a pattern of

`country_name + "guidances/regulations"`

You can get the country name by spilt() method

```
>>> str = 'US guidances/regulations'
>>> myList = str.split(' ') //spilt by the space after the country name
>>> myList[0]
US
>>> myList[1]
guidances/regulations
```

then compare **only the Country name**

```
anotherStr = 'USA guidances/regulations'
anotherList = anotherStr.split(' ') //spilt by the space after the country name
ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(myList[0].lower(), anotherList[0]())
```